# Can't start NGINX on Centos

Tags: nginx, server, centos

I'm starting Nginx with this command: `sudo systemctl start nginx`, but I get this error:

```
 nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
 Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-03-21 17:42:36 MSK; 2min 59s ago
Process: 27647 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 27644 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 27641 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)


 Mar 21 17:42:36 ovz1.pimex.1l0r1.vps.myjino.ru nginx[27647]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
 Mar 21 17:42:36 ovz1.pimex.1l0r1.vps.myjino.ru nginx[27647]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
 Mar 21 17:42:36 ovz1.pimex.1l0r1.vps.myjino.ru systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
 Mar 21 17:42:36 ovz1.pimex.1l0r1.vps.myjino.ru systemd[1]: Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
 Mar 21 17:42:36 ovz1.pimex.1l0r1.vps.myjino.ru systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
 Mar 21 17:42:36 ovz1.pimex.1l0r1.vps.myjino.ru systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.
```

I've checked 80 port:

```
[habrauser@ovz1 system]$ netstat -na | grep ".80"
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: As your netstat shows, the port is in use. Add -p to see what program is using it.

Comment: Ok, I've started Nginx but I can't access my website. In nginx log file I see this `GET / HTTP/1.0" 502 3693 `, don't you know why this can happen?

Answer (score 2):

Add -p to netstat like this: `sudo netstat -na -p | grep ".80"` and it will give you pid of the process that you should `kill`.
Then try `sudo systemctl start nginx`, for me it worked fine.

Allow port for firewall `sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp`